# How to profile the number of additions, mutltiplications etc. with vtune

Tags: c++, performance, x86, profiling, intel-vtune

I am able to profile my C++ library's instruction counts with Vtune using the 'INST_RETIRED.ANY' event.

What analysis types or events can be used profile in terms of number of integer/floating point additions, multiplications, divisions etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(tl:dr): I don't think you can do everything you want with perf counters.  See the end of this answer for a possible way using binary instrumentation

Also note that `imul` is not an expensive operation, and FP mul is barely more expensive than add.  e.g. on Skylake, `mulps`, `addps`, and `fma` all have the same performance (throughput, latency, uops, and choice of execution ports).  On pre-Skylake, add was lower latency but also half throughput, since there's a dedicated add unit.

---

It's not so much what VTUNE can do, as what the hardware performance counters can count.  e.g. [this table of perf-counter events](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/docs/intel-sandybridge-events.php) from Linux oprofile came up when I searched for Sandybridge perf counters.  Also [this more-complete listing for Linux `perf`](http://www.bnikolic.co.uk/blog/hpc-prof-events.html).  If the hardware can count it, I assume VTUNE can show it to you, once you find the right name.

**Test these counters on simple code with known behaviour**, so to make sure they work the way you expect when you already know what the code is doing.

I only looked through what Sandybridge supports.  I assume Haswell/Skylake have these events, too, and probably more.  You didn't say what CPU you have, so I'm not going to check all of them.

Pre-SnB don't have nearly as wide a selection of perf counters, IIRC.  Intel improved perf counters a lot in SnB, along with other big changes to the core.  Big enough that it's generally considered a new microarchitecture family, separate from the P6 family (PPro-Nehalem).

---

**I don't think you can distinguish integer add from integer mul, or FP add from FP mul**.  You can count FP activity, though: `FP_COMP_OPS_EXE` "Counts number of floating point events", with masks for x87 and {packed,scalar}{single,double}.

There's also `SIMD_FP_256`, which counts only 256b vector FP ops.

There's a counter for FP-assist events (when an FP operation needs to fall back to microcode to handle a denormal or something).

I'm not sure this is right, but the `perf` listing says there's a `PARTIAL_RAT_STALLS` with Umask-02 : 0x80: `[MUL_SINGLE_UOP]`: Number of Multiply packed/scalar single precision uops allocated.  It's odd that there's not a similar double-precision counter.  Or maybe `mulss` is somehow special in partial-register behaviour, with PARTIAL_RAT_STALLS has another sub-even to count partial-register merging uops.

---

divide (`div` / `divps`) is slow enough to be worth having a special counter, though:  **SnB's `arith.fpu_div` counter** = "Number of times that the divider is actived, includes INT, SIMD and FP."  There's also a counter for number of *cycles* the divider is active, rather than the number of *times* it was activated.

---

#### How to count instructions:

> [Intel's Pin](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool) is a dynamic binary instrumentation framework for the IA-32 and x86-64 instruction-set architectures that enables the creation of dynamic program analysis tools

I don't have VTUNE, but there may be ways to use Pin tools from within VTUNE.  It will make your code run a slower, potentially a lot slower.  I think it works by JIT-compiling from normal machine code to instrumented machine code, where the instrumentation is extra instructions to increment counters.  It might have other modes of operation, more like single-stepping the original code and counting stuff along the way.

Comment: Update: [Profiling instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1116213) suggests Valgrind's `callgrind` tool.  Similar idea to Intel Pin: basically emulate / interpret the code to allow counting in more detail than HW perf counters.