# Where is integer addition and subtraction event count from intel Vtune?

Tags: c++, profiling, intel, instructions, intel-vtune

I am using intel VTune to profile my program.

The CPU I am using is IVY Bridge.

All the hardware instruction event can be found here:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/589933

> **FP_COMP_OPS_EXE.X87** 
>   Number of FP Computational Uops Executed this
>   cycle. The number of FADD, FSUB, FCOM, FMULs, integer MULsand IMULs,
>   FDIVs, FPREMs, FSQRTS, integer DIVs, and IDIVs. This event does not
>   distinguish an FADD used in the middle of a transcendental flow from a
>   s

FP_COMP_OPS_EXE.X87 seems to include Integer Multiplication and Integer Division; however, there is no Integer Addition and Integer Subtraction there. I can not find those two kinds of instruction either from the above website.

Can anyone tell me what is the event that counts integer addition and integer subtraction instructions?

Comment: There isn't a separate counter for them.  If you want a dynamic count of just `add` / `sub` instructions, and not equally cheap ones like `cmp`, `and`, `xor`, look into [binary instrumentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36650210/how-to-profile-the-number-of-additions-mutltiplications-etc-with-vtune/36658984#36658984).  `add` is one of the cheapest two-input instructions on any normal CPU.  On IvB, runs on any ALU port:  1c latency, one per 0.333c throughput.  Only `mov reg,reg` or a zeroing instruction is cheaper.  See the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).

Answer (score 1):

I'm reading a lot into your question, but here goes:

It's possible that if your code is computationally bound you could find ways to infer the significance of integer adds and subs without measuring them directly.  For example, `UOPS_RETIRED.ALL - FP_COMP_OPS_EXE.ALL` would give you a very rough estimate of adds and subs, assuming that you've already done something to establish that your code is compute bound.

Have you?  If not, it might help to start with VTune's basic analysis and then eliminate memory, cache and front end bottlenecks.  If you've already done this, you have a few more options:

- Cross-reference `UOPS_DISPATCHED_PORT` with an Ivy Bridge block diagram, or even better, a list of which specific types of arithmetic can execute on which ports (which I can't find).
- Modify your program source, compiler flags or assembly, rerun a coarser-grained profile like basic analysis, and see whether you see an impact at the level of a measure like `INST_RETIRED.ANY / CPU_CLK_UNHALTED`.

Sorry there doesn't seem to be a more direct answer.

Comment: Agner Fog has tested which instructions can use which ports, and published [instruction tables](http://agner.org/optimize/).  `add`, `sub`, `xor`, and many other of the simplest integer instructions can run on every ALU port in any CPU.  That's what makes this a silly question: `add` and `sub` aren't special, and compete for the same execution resources as pretty much everything else.  (Unlike FP add and mul, which run on limited ports).

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.  Should have thought to check with Agner.

I agree with the suspicion that this question is more specific than the OP would probably really want to ask in order to address most of the real world use cases I could think of that would lead down this path, but I'm doing my best to read it charitably.  I'm not positive it's "silly".  You could be right though.

Comment: That's true, it's something you might wonder while optimizing a scalar loop that did some integer adds, or wanted to measure `add` as part of loop overhead for pointer increments.  The OP certainly didn't propose any kind of scenario that would explain such a weird request, though.  (That's the other thing: `add` is a normal part of loop overhead, but counting `fadd` only counts "work").  Anyway, your "don't do that, do this instead" answer is more useful advice that actually counting `add` insns with binary instrumentation or something.